# How to run python program in parallel with infinite loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am a beginner in programming, I want to make a program that runs on a different process for example like

one to detect objects,
and the main program performs other commands if the desired object is detected

think this is the process, like API or Realtime Database
https://prnt.sc/KR9iUcM43P9d

I have found several techniques such as **Multi-Threading** and **Multi-Processing**, but what I understand is that they can only get memory data when the program is finished. because when using looping `While True` the data cannot be accepted

is there a technique to do it?

Comment: what you're trying to do is called a _daemon_ (unix) or _service_ (windows) which communicates with other programs via _interprocess communication (IPC)_. Look these words up, but, as a word of warning, these concepts are definitely not something for a "beginner".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.